# Allowing Guest Site User to run reports (for Sp14 charts-in-VF feature)

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, spring14

I was so excited about the Spring '14 [Embed Report Charts in Visualforce Pages](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring14/release-notes/rn_analytics_vf_charts.htm) as a way to present data visualizations on a public site, and now it looks like that's not possible.

I created a page that looks basically like the release notes sample:

```
<apex:page >
    <analytics:reportChart reportId="00OW0000000Spru"></analytics:reportChart>
</apex:page>
```

I tested it inside the authenticated environment, where it works fine, then added it to a Site. There, I get the error: *To view the report chart, you need both the Run Reports permission and access to the report's folder.* But, Run Reports is not a permission I can grant to the Site Guest User.

Anybody have any ideas for a workaround? Or is it not going to be possible to show report charts on a public site?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You aren't going to be able to use out of the box components (like `<analytics:reportChart>`) to run reports as the guest user.

If you want to display reporting data to unauthenticated users, you're going to have to query the data yourself in Apex and use a third party tool (like [D3.js](http://d3js.org/)) or the built in [apex:chart](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_chart.htm) component.

Comment: Ryan, Can you confirm my assumption that the [Analytics API](https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Winter14/AnalyticsAPI) is also not available to the site guest user?

Comment: you are correct, the analytics API is not available to the guest user.