# Expose Report/Dashboard data into Public Sites

Tags: visualforce, reporting, force.com-sites, dashboard, analytics-api

Is it possible to expose report or dashboard data embedded into visualforce page and place it in Public force.com site?
If this is not possible then  please provide me an example to build a custom report using analytics api/d3js/google charts and place it in public force.com site

Comment: Some clarification here... you want to use native report charts and expose them publicly, correct? I ask because you can absolutely expose the data then use HTML or JavaScript to format the data in your own custom chart. Otherwise, I've been told exposing a native chart and report is not possible without having the user authenticate which would require a license for them. Again, I heard that from someone else, not sure how reliable that is.

Comment: yes I want to use native reports and expose them publicly.If that is not possible then build custom report using the data from the native report

Comment: This is very similar to my question here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/27337/allowing-guest-site-user-to-run-reports-for-sp14-charts-in-vf-feature

You can't expose report charts or dashboards directly using Force.com sites, nor can you use the Analytics API directly from a Site.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible, but you have to watch out for licensing discussions. You might need Customer Community licenses to be able to do this.

You might find [this post](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000097eCIAQ) interesting.

Comment: If it requires a customer community license, than that doesn't speak to the original poster's question, which specifies a "public Force.com site."

Comment: @Thomas Taylor Pretty sure those are not two mutually exclusive. Exposing data on a public Force.com site might still require customer community licenses.

Comment: The guest site user cannot be assigned a Communities license and cannot, therefore, be granted the permissions it lacks, like Run Reports, that would allow this. See discussion at my post linked above. Public sites can query data and use VF charting or a third-party charting library. But you can't put a dashboard or report chart built with SF reporting tools directly on them.

Comment: That's not what I am saying. You can write afaik Javascript in your public force.com site to query / edit data in your org. This API call could use authentication of a superuser to get around permission issues. However, this approach breaches the licensing that Salesforce enforces, unless you have sufficient customer community licenses backing this scenario.

Comment: Ok, but by then you're writing custom JS - I'm pretty sure the OP was looking for a nearly declarative solution. If you're going that route, might as well query and build the chart rather than auth and show the chart you built.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible to show report and dashboard to a site. we can do so by either using customer community or partner community license.
you have to do some additional stuff with this
1. creating community.
2. adding the tab of report and dashboard to a community.
3. Rules for the record type.