# i created public site and added the vf page But if i click view it throw The asset cannot displayed because you don't have sufficient permissions

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, force.com-sites

my task is i want to show the einstein dashboards in external web application so i created vf page i tried to add this vf page in public page then web application can use it iframe.but i got error in created public site when i preview like The asset cannot be displayed because you don't have sufficient permissions.
please tell me how to clear it

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL"  extends="ltng:outApp" implements="ltng:allowGuestAccess">  
<aura:dependency resource="c:showDashBoard" type="COMPONENT"/>
</aura:application>

<aura:component access="global" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" >
<aura:attribute name="DashboardId" type="String" default=""/>
<!--<aura:attribute name = "selectedDashboard" type="String" default=""/>-->
<aura:attribute name="BuName" type="String" default=""/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>{!v.body}
</aura:component>


<apex:page >
  <apex:includeLightning />
    <div id="lightning" />
    <script>
       $Lightning.use("c:dashBoard", function() {
         $Lightning.createComponent("c:showDashBoard",
                                    {"DashboardId" :"0FKDn000000XGqdOAG",
                                      },
                                    "lightning",
            
             function(cmp) {
          console.log("c:VFPageApp loaded successfully in VF page");
             }
         );
       });
                     
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see a [related question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/27337/allowing-guest-site-user-to-run-reports-for-sp14-charts-in-vf-feature) which has been already answered.

As per [Salesforce Documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.analytics_folder_viewer.htm&type=5):

> All users have at least Viewer access to report and dashboard folders that have been shared with them. Some users have administrative user permissions that give them greater access. Guest users and Community Portal users can’t access report and dashboard folders.

In your case, the users would not be authenticated in Salesforce, which means that they are considered guest users, which do not have access to report and dashboard folders, so they can not display the report/dashboard.

Displaying reports and dashboards on external sites is essentially a data leak. You can query the data and create your own report to display as an Aura or LWC component instead. However, please note that you have to be careful about what data you make accessible for the guest user.